# What is the time/space complexity of DataTable.Columns.Remove()?

Tags: c#, backend

**TL:DR:**
Basically the title. I tried to look for that info but couldn't find anything.
Let C be the number of columns and R be the number of rows. What would be the complexity of calling the `DataTable.Columns.Remove("BadColumn")` be? I found that to look for the column would take O(C) but what about the data removal? Is it removed immediately or does it wait for GC to do the job?

**Motives:**
So I have an API in C# which calls an SQL Stored Procedure that returns me a `DataTable` upon which I do additional calculations that are not possible or uncomfortable to do on the SQL server. Later I return that `DataTable` to the frontend with additional information outside the table. The problem is that the `DataTable` contains a lot of columns that are used in API for calculations and useless for frontend. So I wanted to try and remove the columns that are irrelevant for the front to reduce the load on the network since it shrinks a ~2mb JSON into ~1.4mb. On the other hand the time difference used to download the JSON  will go into the calculations of removing the columns hence me seeking the answer. It is important to note that both options work pretty much instantaneously and the question is for learning and understanding only.

Comment: In a language such as C#, the GC always removes data. However, when your application "deletes" the data it will no longer be accessible, so you really shouldn't worry about _when_ the garbage collector does it's job - if it's removing something from memory then the data is already gone from your application's perspective.

Comment: Since removing the column removes the data I would assume the complexity is O(C) + O(R) (since you're mentioning GC here, "removes the data" only means unlinks the data from the underlying rows, it does not invoke nor wait for GC to completely remove those items from memory)

Comment: Don't remove the column; just don't serialize it. Most serialization libraries allow you to mark properties as "do not serialize".

Comment: Note that according to [this](https://dudusd.wordpress.com/2008/11/23/efficiency-of-datacolumncollection-contains/) (fishy) website, the "contains" is using a hash table so the time is O(1) and not O(C).